# How to get a single $interval() call from the controller

Tags: angularjs

I would like my controller to refresh some services (need to call a webservice) every minutes, so i wrote:

```
angular.module('App').controller('dashboardCtrl', function($scope, $interval, ServiceOne, ServiceTwo, ServiceThree) {
    ServiceOne.init();
    ServiceTwo.init();
    ServiceThree.init();
    //... n

    this.refreshServices = function() {
      ServiceOne.refresh();
      ServiceTwo.refresh();
      ServiceThree.refresh();
      //... n
    };

    $interval(funcion() {
      var self = this;
      self.refreshServices();
    });

});
```

The problem is, the controller is fired 2 times by angular, so 2 `$interval` are working at the same time.

How to avoid this ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $timeout will only execute your refreshing once, when the time you set has run out.

In my opinion, this kind of logic does nog belong inside the controller, and should be moved to the .run() block of your module, or perhaps inside the service itself?

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

For recurring events, you're better of using $interval:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval#!
The examples for $interval give an example of how to avoid starting an interval twice too.

Check out .run() on the module doc page:
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: Thanks for intrudicing me to `$interval()` i didn't find it so i thought angular only used `$timeout()`.

I had this logic in my service when i only wanted to refresh one of them, but now i have plenty, i think the controller is the best place.

`run` could also be an option but the app will be always working on this treatment even when it's not necessary (when we are on another view).